# Let $a \in G$ and suppose $aH = Hb$ for some $b \in G$. Then $aH=Ha$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This statement is made in Aluffi, Algebra: Chapter $0$.

> [image]

---

Let $a \in G$ and suppose $aH = Hb$ for some $b \in G$. How do we proceed?

Comment: Context:  you should include the information that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, if that is the case

Comment: Please include your toughts on the problem: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 8):

As the text says, $a\in aH\cap Ha$.  So the two right cosets $Hb$ and $Ha$ intersect (they both contain $a$), and thus must be equal.  To put it another way, if $aH$ is equal to a right coset, it must be equal to the right coset that contains $a$, which is $Ha$.

Answer (score 7):

Assume $H$ is a subgroup ... then there exist $ h \in H$ such that $a=hb$. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
Ha=Hhb=Hb=aH.
\end{eqnarray*}